# ¿Qué es if __name__ == “__main__”:?

Tags: python

Es común encontrarnos código con esta forma:

```
def hacer_algo():
    print("algo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hacer_algo()
```

En lugar de, por ejemplo:

```
def hacer_algo():
    print("algo")

hacer_algo()
```

También notamos que la variable `__name__` no es inicializada por nosotros, pero existe en el entorno.

- ¿Cuál es la diferencia?
- ¿Por qué preferir uno sobre el otro?
- ¿Qué es y cómo funciona?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Esto está íntimamente ligado al modo de funcionamiento del intérprete Python:

- Cuando el intérprete lee un archivo de código, **ejecuta todo el código global que se encuentra en él**. Esto implica crear objetos para toda función o clase definida y variables globales.
- Todo módulo (archivo de código) en Python tiene un atributo especial llamado `__name__` que define el espacio de nombres en el que se está ejecutando. Es usado para identificar de forma única un módulo en el sistema de importaciones.
- Por su parte `"__main__"` es el nombre del ámbito en el que se ejecuta el código de nivel superior (tu programa principal).
- El intérprete pasa el valor del atributo `__name__` a la cadena `'__main__'` si el módulo se está ejecutando como programa principal (cuando lo ejecutas llamando al intérprete en la terminal con `python my_modulo.py`, haciendo doble click en él, ejecutándolo en el intérprete interactivo, etc ).
- Si el módulo no es llamado como programa principal, sino que es importado desde otro módulo, el atributo `__name__` pasa a contener el nombre del archivo en si.

[Aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) tienes la documentación oficial.

Es decir, si tienes un archivo llamado `mi_modulo.py`, si lo ejecutamos como programa principal el atributo `__name__` será `'__main__'`, si lo usamos importándolo desde otro módulo (`import mi_modulo`) el atributo `__name__` será igual a `'mi_modulo'`.

Básicamente, lo que haces usando `if __name__ == “__main__”:` es ver si el módulo ha sido ejecutado directamente o no (importado). **Si se ha ejecutado como programa principal se ejecuta el código dentro del condicional.**

Una de las razones para hacerlo es que, a veces, se escribe un módulo (un archivo .py) que se puede ejecutar directamente pero que, alternativamente, también se puede importar y reutilizar sus funciones, clases, métodos, etc en otro módulo.

En frameworks gráficos por ejemplo es común generar un ejemplo de uso del widget o widgets definidos en ese módulo que sirve de ejemplo de uso y para testear el propio módulo. Si ejecutas el módulo tendremos una interfaz gráfica de ejemplo, pero ni que decir tiene que cuando importamos el módulo para usar el widget no queremos que nos aparezca una ventanita por ahí por amor al arte. Un ejemplo real en el framework [Kivy](https://kivy.org/):

- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/accordion.py

Con el uso del condicional  conseguimos que la ejecución sea diferente al ejecutar el módulo directamente que al importarlo desde otro módulo. Todo lo que hay dentro del condicional será completamente ignorado por el interprete cuando se importa el módulo, pero no cuando se ejecute como módulo principal.

Para ver como funciona puedes probar algún código (siguiendo tu propio ejemplo):

Creas un módulo al que llamaremos `mi_modulo.py`:

```
print("¡Hola desde mi_modulo.py!")

def hacer_algo():
    print("¡Soy una función y hago algo!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Ejecutando como programa principal')
    hacer_algo()

print("¡Adiós desde mi_módulo.py!")  # Debajo del condicional pero fuera del mismo
```

En la misma carpeta creas otro módulo al que llamaremos `principal.py`

```
import mi_modulo

print("¡Hola desde principal.py!")
mi_modulo.hacer_algo()
print("¡Adiós desde principal.py!")
```

Si ejecutas el script `mi_modulo.py` directamente:

```
$ python mi_modulo.py
```

el valor de `__name__` será `"__main__"` y se ejecutará el bloque que hay dentro del `if __name__ == “__main__”:`:

> ¡Hola desde mi_modulo.py!
>   Ejecutando como programa principal
>   ¡Soy una función y hago algo!
>   ¡Adiós desde mi_modulo.py!

Si ejecutamos el archivo `principal.py` que usa `mi_modulo.py` importándolo no se cumple la condición `if __name__ == “__main__”` por lo que solo se ejecuta el código global (el `print` inicial y se crea el objeto función `hacer_algo` en memoria). La función solo se ejecuta cuando la llamamos desde el módulo principal:

> ¡Hola desde mi_modulo.py!
>   ¡Adiós desde mi_modulo.py!
>   ¡Hola desde principal.py!
>   ¡Soy una función y hago algo!
>   ¡Adiós desde principal.py!

Ahora vamos a cambiar el script `mi_modulo.py` por:

```
print("¡Hola desde mi_modulo.py!")

def hacer_algo():
    print("¡Soy una función y hago algo!")

hacer_algo()
print("¡Adiós desde mi_modulo.py!"))
```

Si lo ejecutamos como programa principal el resultado es el mismo que antes, pero si ejecutamos ahora `principal.py` nos sale esto:

> ¡Hola desde mi_modulo.py!
>   ¡Soy una función y hago algo!
>   ¡Adiós desde mi_modulo.py!
>   ¡Hola desde principal.py!
>   ¡Soy una función y hago algo!
>   ¡Adiós desde principal.py!

Lo que pasa es que al importar ejecutamos todo el código del módulo importado, incluyendo la llamada a la función que ahora no está envuelta en el condicional. Una vez importado el módulo principal llama a la función importada de nuevo.

En definitiva, las dos formas que pones son válidas si ejecutas el script siempre como programa principal, si lo usas también importándolo no sueles querer que se ejecute código si no llamas a una función tu mismo y esa es la razón de usar `if __name__ == “__main__”:`

Comment: A modo de curiosidad, decir que si se usa el intérprete *bpython* para ejecutar los programas, el atributo `__name__` del módulo principal no es `"__main__"`, sino que es `"__console__"`.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez gracias por el apunte, la verdad es que no conocía bpython ("nunca te irás a dormir sin saber algo nuevo"), voy a informarme a ver que ofrece :). Supongo que existen más variantes a la forma estándar que usa CPython (aunque todas siguen el mismo principio), otra que se me ocurre es al usar Kivy en Android, donde se usa  `"__android__"`. Saludos.

Comment: Genial, gracias, tampoco sabía lo de android. *Bpython* es más una interfaz mejorada en la terminal al intérprete Python que un intérprete en sí mismo. Aquí te paso el enlace: https://bpython-interpreter.org/

Answer (score 9):

la instrucción `if`, del tipo:

```py
if __name__ == “__main__”:
    # (bloque cosas dentro)
```

sirve para aislar o desacoplar la ejecución del *`(bloque de cosas dentro)`* dentro de un programa (condición true), a cuando se importa totalmente dicho programa en otro.

En ese caso, al ejecutar este otro, no se ejecutará el *`(bloque de cosas dentro)`* por tener condición false.

Así permito realizar cosas distintas con el mismo programa (directo vs importado).

Answer (score 6):

Es la funcion principal del programa se utiliza para inicializar el programa para ello simplemente haces lo siguiente desde la cmd:

```
python tuejemplo.py
```

Y el programa se inicializa y ejecuta. Por otro lado, porque utilizar este método porque puedes arrancarlo o cuando quieres agregarlo como módulo entonces el programa no se arrancará yo pienso que esa es la unica diferencia.

Answer (score 5):

Voy a explicarlo lo más simple posible ya que entiendo que muchas personas no lo entienden, como yo en su momento no había podido entender esta sentencia o mejor dicho esta condición.

`if __name__ == "__main__"`:

Esta condición simplemente hace una consulta para verificar si el archivo que se está ejecutando es el archivo principal o raíz del programa. En Python el método `__name__` es el nombre de tu archivo.
Ejemplo: calculadora.py >> ella tomará `__name__` el nombre de tu archivo .py y lo comparará con el `__main__` que siempre será para Python el archivo principal, el archivo con mayor jerarquía.

Pero seguramente te preguntarás ¿qué sentido tiene? ¿Para qué voy a perder tiempo en crear una condición si quiero que se ejecute el programa y ya?

La respuesta a esto está en que imaginemos una aplicación con miles de archivos .py y te asignan ese proyecto que ya venía haciendo otra persona, ¿cómo lograrías saber cuál es tu archivo raíz? ¿cuál es el comienzo de todo? ¡Quizás comiences por uno que creas que era el raíz y no lo es!

Creo que esta sería una de las principales razones (de las tantas razones) por las cuales usar `if __name__ == "__ main__"`.

No es obligatorio pero es una buena práctica usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

La línea `if name == 'main:'` es una construcción comúnmente utilizada en Python para controlar la ejecución del código en un archivo.

Cuando un archivo de Python se ejecuta, Python asigna el nombre "`main`" al archivo. La línea `if name == 'main':` comprueba si el archivo actual se está ejecutando como el archivo principal del programa.

Si se está ejecutando como el archivo principal, es decir, si no se está importando desde otro archivo, el código dentro del bloque "`if`" se ejecutará. Si el archivo está siendo importado desde otro archivo, el bloque "`if`" no se ejecutará.

Esta construcción es útil porque permite escribir código que se ejecuta solo cuando se ejecuta el archivo como un programa independiente y no cuando se importa como un módulo en otro programa.