# como def importando turtle

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando en un programa para hacer figuras usando turtle en `python`, pero quiero definir una función para que a la hora de invocarla haga la figura, hice anteriormente este código pero cuando lo pruebo no pasa nada.

```
import turtle
def cuadrado():
   turtle.pen()
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido a stackoverflow, el problema es que solo estás definiendo la función pero no la ejecutas, para ello simplemente usas el nombre seguido de parentesis. Dentro de ellos le pasas los parámetros que necesite, en tu caso no tiene parámetros. Es decir al final de tu código añades:

`cuadrado()`

Quedaría así:

```
import turtle

def cuadrado():
   turtle.pen()
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)

cuadrado()
```

También puedes usar esta forma:

```
import turtle

def cuadrado():
   turtle.pen()
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)
   turtle.left(90)
   turtle.forward(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cuadrado()
```

En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32165/qu%C3%A9-es-if-name-main) pregunta se explica como funciona.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias entonses si pongo print(cuadrado) se activa la funcion eh inprimiria el codigo para dibujar el cuadrado?

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con imprimir el código? ¿quieres que se imprima por pantalla lo que hay dentro de la función?¿Que se imprima la función en si como si fuera texto?

Comment: oh ya entendi,ya vi la pregunta que me indicaste y ya entendi como hacerle para mi codigo muchas gracias