# Ejecutar cadena de archivos python

Tags: python, terminal

Quiero ejecutar varios programas similares uno tras otro en la terminal.

```
archivo1.py
archivo2.py
archivo3.py
```

No debo unir los 3 archivos y crear 1 solo con las funciones de los tres, lo que estoy buscando es que pueda crear un archivo nuevo con una funcion que llame a esos 3 archivos a ejecutarse!

Una posible solucion es esta pero no me funciona:

```
import archivo1
import archivo2
import archivo3
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

no se que poner luego de los dos puntos y si los archivos no van con el .py y comillas o algo

Desde ya muchas gracias

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

La forma más simple es usando [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

```
import os

os.system("python archivo1.py")
os.system("python archivo2.py")
os.system("python archivo3.py")
```

Sino, otra forma que ofrece mayor control es usando [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) que vale la pena ver la documentación

```
import subprocess

process1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'archivo1.py'])
process2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'archivo2.py'])
process3 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'archivo3.py'])
```

Comment: con el primer metodo me da error. Con el segundo me los abre en simultaneo y eso no puedo hacerlo. Tiene que empezar 1 y cuando termina ese arranca el otro

Comment: @MartinBouhier , que error te da?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python
import os

os.system("Archivo.py")
os.system("Archivo2.py")
os.system("Archivo3.py")`
Error:
`sh: Archivo.py: command not found
32512`

Comment: @MartinBouhier:  No estaría encontrando el script `Archivo.py` revisa si es correcto el nombre.

Answer (score 0):

El método propuesto por Patricio permite crear un proceso por cada uno de los módulos. Es una buena opción si solo vas a ejecutar los script. Recuerda dar permisos de ejecución a los script para el usuario oportuno.

También puedes simplemente importarlos. Esto simplemente ejecutará el contenido de cada script secuecialmente en el orden de los imports:

**main.py**:

```
import archivo1
import archivo2
import archivo3
```

El archivo debe estar en el mismo directorio que los tres archivos anteriores.

El código de cada modulo es ejecutado excepto aquel que tengas dentro de:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Para saber más sobre la sentencia anterior se puede ver la siguiente publicación:

[¿Qué es if __name__ == “__main__”:?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/32165/15089)

---

**Edición:**

El problema es que al incluir el carácter "$" en el nombre de tu módulo no es un identificador valido y no puede ser importado. Por norma general **no deberías nombrar tus módulos con identificadores no válidos**, no obstante, puedes importar de la siguiente forma:

```
archivo1 = __import__('archivoMW$1')
archivo2 = __import__('archivoMW$2')
archivo3 = __import__('archivoMW$3')
```

O simplemente:

```
__import__('archivoMW$1')
__import__('archivoMW$2')
__import__('archivoMW$3')
```

Repito que lo ideal seria nombrar los módulos con identificadores válidos.

Comment: No comprendo como seria el codigo entero del programa, me lo puedes escribir editando la respuesta por favor??

Comment: Modifique mi pregunta para ver en que le estoy errando....

Comment: Okey entendi pero no puedo hacer que funcione cuando importo. el nombre real es archivoMW$2.py tendra algo qe ver el nombre??

Comment: Modifique el nombre a arc1, arc2 y arc3 y anduvo pero no quiero tener que cambiar de nombre los archivos. Nombre original es archivoMW$2.5.py Corrijo. Ese punto del 2.5 es el que complica todo creo

Comment: Ya pude, tenia que agregarle el .py a los archuvos!!!

Comment: @MartinBouhier elimina cualquier identacion o espacio delante de cada linea. Error mio al copiar... voy a editar...