# Runtine error al usar multiprocesos en Windows: freeze_suport()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, proceso, wav

Este es el código de un reproductor de audio (.wav), que usa Matplotlib para graficar el espectro, que he estado modificando:

```
import matplotlib
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import numpy as np

import multiprocessing

duration = 12.5
filename = '1.wav'

wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')

def dB(a,base=1.0):
    return 10.0*np.log10(a/base)

fs = wf.getframerate()
bytes_per_sample = wf.getsampwidth()
bits_per_sample  = bytes_per_sample * 8
dtype = 'int{0}'.format(bits_per_sample)
channels = wf.getnchannels()

def audiostream(queue, n_channels, sampling, n_bytes_per_sample):
    # open stream
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format =
                    p.get_format_from_width(n_bytes_per_sample),
                    channels = n_channels,
                    rate = sampling,
                    output = True)


    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        print ("input latency: {0}".format(stream.get_input_latency()))
        print ("output latency: {0}".format(stream.get_output_latency()))
        print ("avail read: {0}".format(stream.get_read_available()))
        print ("avail write: {0}".format(stream.get_write_available()))
        if data == 'Stop':
            break
        stream.write(data)
    stream.close()

Q = multiprocessing.Queue()
audio_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=audiostream, args=(Q,channels,fs,bytes_per_sample))
audio_process.start()
# audio_process.join()
# stream = Q.get()
# audio_process.join()

# read data
audio = np.fromstring(wf.readframes(int(duration*fs*bytes_per_sample/channels)), dtype=dtype)
audio.shape = (audio.shape[0]/channels, channels)

ch_left = 0
ch_right = 1

ch = ch_right

audio_fft = np.fft.fft(audio[:,ch])
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(audio[:,ch].shape[0], 1.0/fs) / 1000.0
max_freq_kHz = freqs.max()
times = np.arange(audio.shape[0]) / float(fs)
fftshift = np.fft.fftshift

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,11))
ax_spec_gram = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax_fft  = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax_time = fig.add_subplot(313)

ax_spec_gram.specgram(audio[:,ch], Fs=fs, cmap='gist_heat')
ax_spec_gram.set_xlim(0,duration)
ax_spec_gram.set_ylim(0,max_freq_kHz*1000.0)
ax_spec_gram.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')

ax_fft.plot(fftshift(freqs), fftshift(dB(audio_fft)))
ax_fft.set_xlim(0,max_freq_kHz)
ax_fft.set_xlabel('Frequency (kHz)')
ax_fft.set_ylabel('dB')

ax_time.plot(times, audio[:,ch])
ax_time.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax_time.set_xlim(0,duration)
ax_time.set_ylim(-32768,32768)

time_posn, = ax_time.plot([0,0], [-32768,32768], 'k')
spec_posn, = ax_spec_gram.plot([0,0], [0, max_freq_kHz*1000.0], 'k')


class AudioSubsetter(object):
    def __init__(self, audio_array, audio_device_queue, n_channels, sampling_rate, n_bytes_per_sample, chunk_dt=0.1):
        self.last_chunk = -1
        self.queue = audio_device_queue
        self.audio_dat = audio_array.tostring()
        self.to_t = 1.0/(sampling_rate*n_channels*n_bytes_per_sample)
        chunk = int(chunk_dt*fs)*channels*bytes_per_sample
        self.chunk0 = np.arange(0, len(self.audio_dat), chunk, dtype=int)
        self.chunk1 = self.chunk0 + chunk

    def update(self, *args):
        """ Timer callback for audio position indicator. Called with """
        self.last_chunk +=1
        if self.last_chunk >= len(self.chunk0):
            # self.queue.put("Stop")
            self.last_chunk = 0

        i = self.last_chunk
        i0, i1 = self.chunk0[i], self.chunk1[i]
        self.queue.put(self.audio_dat[i0:i1])
        t0, t1 = i0*self.to_t, i1*self.to_t
        print( t0, t1)
        for line_artist in args:
            line_artist.set_xdata([t1,t1])
        args[0].figure.canvas.draw()


print ("Setting up audio process")
dt = .5
playhead = AudioSubsetter(audio, Q, channels, fs, bytes_per_sample, chunk_dt=dt)
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=dt*1000.0)
timer.add_callback(playhead.update, spec_posn, time_posn)
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

el problema es que al ejecutarlo en Windows obtengo un ***Runtime Error***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un efecto colateral debido a la limitación que hay en Windows al carecer este de `os.fork` y de su funcionalidad. Esta característica presente en muchos sistemas operativos modernos permite básicamente bifurcar 
un proceso haciendo un duplicado exacto de sí mismo y heredando todos los recursos del padre. Al crearse un nuevo proceso se permite que las modificaciones en uno de ellos no afecta al otro (efectos colaterales). Esto incluye por supuesto al interprete de Python cuando ha de ejecutar código en otro proceso.

En Windows esto se hace mediante `spawn` ("*generación*") que no crea una copia idéntica, sino que inicia un proceso limpio heredando solo una parte imprescindible de los recursos del proceso padre, siendo un método más lento.

Puedes mirarte la documentación oficial para más información:

[Multiprocessing - Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)

[Básicamente al usar spawn el módulo que llana el subproceso es ejecutado al completo en un nuevo intérprete](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256703/por-qu%C3%A9-una-variable-global-no-mantiene-su-valor-cuando-pasa-a-un-proceso-hijo/256720#256720), importando todos los módulos de nuevo y **ejecutando todo el código a nivel global que exista**. Lógicamente esto puede ocasionar que la linea que lanza el subproceso sea ejecutada en el nuevo subproceso también, ocasionando que otro subproceso se lance desde el propio subproceso hijo original y así sucesivamente. Para permitir que el intérprete pueda importar el módulo principal de forma segura sin causar efectos colaterales, se debe usar `if __name__ == "__main__"` cuando trabajes con *multiprocess* y crees un nuevo proceso en tu módulo principal.

[¿Qué es if __name__ == “__main__”:?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/32165/15089)

En tu caso lo más simple es que englobes tu código que está ahora a nivel  global en una función (p.e `main`) y la llames desde dentro del condicional `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
import wave

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import pyaudio



def dB(a,base=1.0):
    return 10.0*np.log10(a/base)

def audiostream(queue, n_channels, sampling, n_bytes_per_sample):
    # open stream
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format =
                    p.get_format_from_width(n_bytes_per_sample),
                    channels = n_channels,
                    rate = sampling,
                    output = True)

    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        print ("input latency: {0}".format(stream.get_input_latency()))
        print ("output latency: {0}".format(stream.get_output_latency()))
        print ("avail read: {0}".format(stream.get_read_available()))
        print ("avail write: {0}".format(stream.get_write_available()))
        if data == 'Stop':
            break
        stream.write(data)
    stream.close()


class AudioSubsetter(object):
    def __init__(self, audio_array, audio_device_queue, n_channels, sampling_rate, n_bytes_per_sample, chunk_dt=0.1):
        self.last_chunk = -1
        self.queue = audio_device_queue
        self.audio_dat = audio_array.tostring()
        self.to_t = 1.0/(sampling_rate*n_channels*n_bytes_per_sample)
        chunk = int(chunk_dt*sampling_rate)*n_channels*n_bytes_per_sample
        self.chunk0 = np.arange(0, len(self.audio_dat), chunk, dtype=int)
        self.chunk1 = self.chunk0 + chunk

    def update(self, *args):
        """ Timer callback for audio position indicator. Called with """
        self.last_chunk +=1
        if self.last_chunk >= len(self.chunk0):
            # self.queue.put("Stop")
            self.last_chunk = 0

        i = self.last_chunk
        i0, i1 = self.chunk0[i], self.chunk1[i]
        self.queue.put(self.audio_dat[i0:i1])
        t0, t1 = i0*self.to_t, i1*self.to_t
        print( t0, t1)
        for line_artist in args:
            line_artist.set_xdata([t1,t1])
        args[0].figure.canvas.draw()



def main():
    duration = 12.5
    filename = 'o.wav'
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')

    fs = wf.getframerate()
    bytes_per_sample = wf.getsampwidth()
    bits_per_sample  = bytes_per_sample * 8
    dtype = 'int{0}'.format(bits_per_sample)
    channels = wf.getnchannels()

    Q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    audio_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=audiostream, args=(Q,channels,fs,bytes_per_sample))
    audio_process.start()
    # audio_process.join()
    # stream = Q.get()
    # audio_process.join()

    # read data
    audio = np.fromstring(wf.readframes(int(duration*fs*bytes_per_sample/channels)), dtype=dtype)
    audio.shape = (audio.shape[0]//channels, channels)

    ch_left = 0
    ch_right = 1

    ch = ch_right

    audio_fft = np.fft.fft(audio[:,ch])
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(audio[:,ch].shape[0], 1.0/fs) / 1000.0
    max_freq_kHz = freqs.max()
    times = np.arange(audio.shape[0]) / float(fs)
    fftshift = np.fft.fftshift

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,11))
    ax_spec_gram = fig.add_subplot(311)
    ax_fft  = fig.add_subplot(312)
    ax_time = fig.add_subplot(313)

    ax_spec_gram.specgram(audio[:,ch], Fs=fs, cmap='gist_heat')
    ax_spec_gram.set_xlim(0,duration)
    ax_spec_gram.set_ylim(0,max_freq_kHz*1000.0)
    ax_spec_gram.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')

    ax_fft.plot(fftshift(freqs), fftshift(dB(audio_fft)))
    ax_fft.set_xlim(0,max_freq_kHz)
    ax_fft.set_xlabel('Frequency (kHz)')
    ax_fft.set_ylabel('dB')

    ax_time.plot(times, audio[:,ch])
    ax_time.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax_time.set_xlim(0,duration)
    ax_time.set_ylim(-32768,32768)

    time_posn, = ax_time.plot([0,0], [-32768,32768], 'k')
    spec_posn, = ax_spec_gram.plot([0,0], [0, max_freq_kHz*1000.0], 'k')


    print ("Setting up audio process")
    dt = .5
    playhead = AudioSubsetter(audio, Q, channels, fs, bytes_per_sample, chunk_dt=dt)
    timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=int(dt*1000))
    timer.add_callback(playhead.update, spec_posn, time_posn)
    timer.start()

    plt.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Tenias algunos errores en el constructor de tu clase al usar variables globales en vez de los argumentos pasados al propio `__init__`.

Comment: gracias me has ayudado bastante