# remplazar el if __name__ == '__main__': por alguna otra funcion o explicarme esta en este ejercicio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Podrian ayudarme a cambiar el `if __name__ == '__main__':` o el quien sabe como funciona , me ayudaria a entender lo que hace  en este codigo?

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Ingrese la cantidad de personas:")
    n = int(input())
    acum = 0
    acum2 = 0
    acum3 = 0
    personas = 1.70
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print("Ingrese la altura de la  ",i," persona:")
        dato = float(input())
        if dato >= personas:
         acum2 = acum2+1
        if dato < personas:
         acum3 = acum3+1
        acum = acum+dato
    prom = acum/n

    print ("#####################") 
    print ("Las personas menores a la altura de 1.70 cm ""son:",acum3,)
    print ("#####################")
    print ("Las personas mayores o iguales a la altura de 1.70 cm ""son:",acum2,)
    print ("#####################")
    print("El promedio de altura de las" ,n,"personas son:",prom,)
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, mírate la siguiente pregunta: [¿Qué es if \_\_name\_\_ == “\_\_main\_\_”:?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/32165/15089). Básicamente esa línea no es más que un condicional que permite que el código que tiene en su interior solo se ejecute cuando el módulo sea ejecutado como módulo principal y no en otros casos (si es importado desde otro módulo por ejemplo).  Para el script que muestras no tiene una utilidad real en principio, podrías eliminarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: En principio ésta pregunta es un duplicado, aún así si tienes dudas que no se resuelvan en la pregunta enlazada o crees que tu pregunta difiere de ésta en realidad solo comenta.

Comment: Es que he intentado cambiar el if por def , pero no logro realizarlo , podrias ayudarme a cambiar ese if _ name  sin que se altere mi codigo? Gracias

Comment: Para englobar el  código que ahora tienes en el condicional en una función simplemente tienes que cambiar esa línea por una en la que definas una función (por ejemplo `def main():`) y luego solo tienes que llamar a la función para ejecutar el código (`main()`), algo así: https://repl.it/repls/NumbFittingBlock

Comment: También puedes borrar sin más la línea del `if` (y "desindentar" todo el código que va después, claro)