# No puedo importar paquetes en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

El dia de hoy trabajando en un proyecto tuve que recurrir a tratar de importar paquetes a la inversa es decir archivos en un directorio superior,para ubicarlos un poco esta seria mi jerarquia

- proyecto
- image.py
- AllSource

  - source
  - installerfiles

    - installclient

      - Firstinstall.py
  - message

    - ErrorMessage.py

Lo que necesito es hacer 2 importaciones

La primera es desde `Fisrtinstall.py` importar el archivo  `image.py`

y la segunda es que de `Firstinstall.py` importar `ErrorMessage.py`

para lo cual trate de hacer lo siguiente

**Esto desde Firstinstall.py**

`from ..image.py import imageClass`
`from ..message.ErrorMessage import Errorclass`

pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

**Actualizacion**

Despues de seguir la explicacion dada en la respuesta, trate de hacer un ejemplo mas simple con la siguiente estructura:

```
foo.py 
paquete
    subpaquete1
        subpaquete2
            modulo1.py
    bar.py  
    modulo2.py
```

cada archivo.py contienen una funcion simple como esta:

```
def saludarNOMBRE():
    print("hola")
```

para importar el modulo2 desde el modulo1

escribí lo siguiente:

```
from ...modulo2 import modulo2hola
```

el error aparece de nuevo

nota: Para ejecutar estos archivos utilizo atom y la extension que permite ejecutar el archivo al instante presionando F5 no se si eso tiene algo que ver, con esto quiere decir que si tengo abierto el archivo modulo1.py presiono f5 y se ejecuta al instante.

Esta es la ruta completa en el sistema de donde se ubica mi proyecto:

```
C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\TES\paquete\subpaquete1\subpaquete2
```

Comment: @FJSevilla importado y usado por otro

Comment: @FJSevilla. soy nuevo en este temas podrias si fueras tan amable de explicarme un poco mejor lo de los impprts relativos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Los imports relativos son unos "animales" curiosos en Python, voy a ver si puedo explicar su funcionamiento de forma más o menos resumida.

Empecemos por el principio, en Python hay dos formas diferentes de ejecutar un archivo:

- **Como script principal**

  En este caso el archivo es ejecutado directamente, es el primer archivo que el intérprete ejecuta, sirviendo de punto de entrada de nuestra aplicación. Solo puede haber uno por tanto. Ejecutamos un script como principal cuando en la terminal hacemos:

  > $ python miscript.py

  Siempre que el intérprete ejecuta un archivo, le asigna un nombre. Dicho nombre se asocia al atributo especial  `__name__` del objeto que representa el módulo. En el caso de que se ejecute como principal, [su nombre es siempre `"__main__"]`[1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32165/qu%C3%A9-es-if-name-main/32185#32185).

  **Cuando un módulo se ejecuta como principal es imposible importar nada que esté por encima de su directorio padre sin recurrir a modificar PYTHONPATH o `sys.path`**, lo cual no suele ser tampoco buena idea en la mayoría de los casos, dado que se puede evitar esta situación generalmente reestructurando correctamente el proyecto.
- **Como módulo / importado**

  Otra forma de ejecutar un archivo es de forma indirecta importándolo desde otro archivo ejecutado o también desde la terminal con:

  > $ python -m miscript

  En este caso, el nombre del módulo se compone del nombre del archivo precedido del nombre de todos los paquetes y subpaquetes de los que forma parte, usando un punto (`.`) para separarlos.

Todo parece más o menos simple, pero hay un punto importante a tener en cuenta. En el caso de que un modulo contenido en un paquete sea importado, su nombre depende también de la ruta del archivo principal ejecutado, mejor un ejemplo:

> ```
> foo.py
> paquete
>     subpaquete1
>         subpaquete2
>             modulo1.py
>
>     modulo2.py
>     bar.py
> ```

si en <kbd>foo.py</kbd> (ejecutado como script principal) importamos  <kbd>modulo1.py</kbd> el nombre de `modulo1` queda como:

```
paquete.subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1
```

si importamos desde <kbd>bar.py</kbd>  (dentro del paquete) su nombre queda como:

```
subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1
```

Esto se debe a que cuando Python busca el módulo importado coloca el directorio actual al inicio de sus directorios de búsqueda, si encuentra el módulo en ese directorio o en un subdirectorio no sabe ni tiene en cuenta si forma parte de un paquete o no. En nuestro ejemplo, al importar desde <kbd>bar.py</kbd> se pierde la información de que `subpaquete1`, `modulo2.py` y `bar.py` forman parte de un paquete superior (`paquete`). Como veremos, esto hay que tenerlo muy en cuenta.

Bien, como comentaba al inicio los imports relativos son algo especiales, esto se debe a que **no se resuelven en base a la estructura del árbol de archivos en el disco, sino en base al nombre del módulo**. Por eso entender todo lo anterior es crucial.

Cuando hacemos `from .. import algo` cada `.` indica subir un nivel en la estructura de paquetes. En el momento en el que intentemos subir más niveles de los que existen en el nombre del archivo tendremos el error que mencionas:

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Esto puede pasar por dos razones:

- Hemos ejecutado el módulo como script principal, en cuyo caso su nombre es `"__main__"`.
- Hemos importado el módulo desde un script situado en el mismo directorio o en un nivel inferior al que el import relativo del módulo importado trata de acceder. En el caso que mencionamos antes:

Para que <kbd>modulo1.py</kbd> pueda importar <kbd>modulo2.py</kbd> debemos hacer:

```
from ... import modulo2
```

Si luego importamos `modulo1` desde desde <kbd>foo.py</kbd> a través de su paquete:

```
import paquete.subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1
```

no tenemos ningún problema. Pero si intentamos hacer los mismo desde <kbd>bar.py</kbd>:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "bar.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1 
>   File "/test/package/paquete/subpaquete1/subpaquete2/modulo1.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from ... import modulo2
> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
> ```

Esto se debe a lo explicado antes, al importar <kbd>modulo1.py</kbd> desde <kbd>bar.py</kbd> el nombre de este queda como:

```
subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1
```

como intenta hacer un import con tres "puntos" y tiene dos en su nombre por lo que interpreta que pretendemos hacer lo que el error dice:

> Intento de importación relativa más allá del paquete de nivel superior

el paquete de nivel superior en este caso es `subpaquete1` no `paquete` como ocurría al importar `modulo1` desde `foo.py`.

Resumiendo, los imports relativos solo deben usarse y solo funcionarán normalmente dentro de paquetes.

---

En tu caso, los imports relativos correctos en <kbd>Fisrtinstall.py</kbd> serían:

```
from ....image import imageClass
from ...message.ErrorMessage import Errorclass
```

pero ten en cuenta todo lo comentado antes, en especial si intentas ejecutar como script principal un módulo del paquete.

Comment: agradezco mucho tu explicacion y trate de entender y aplicar todo lo que me has dicho pero aun que trate de aplicarlo a un ejemplo mas simple me sale el mismo error de top-level

Comment: Angel la clave está como trato de explicar dónde se localiza el módulo que ejecutas como principal y que importa tu paquete o uno de sus módulos. Para que lo anterior funcione ese modulo debe estar fuera del paquete (proyecto en tu caso). Ten cuidado con los IDEs, pueden modificar la ruta de trabajo del script ejecutado. Si no te aclaras, comenta explicando como usas el paquete y desde dónde a ver si podemos aclarar lo que te está pasando.

Comment: he actualizado la informacion de el codigo esperando ayude

Comment: Angel ten en cuenta que no puedes ejecutar `modulo1.py` directamente, esto ejecuta el módulo como principal y como explico esto inhabilita de facto  cualquier import relativo. Si quieres ejecutar  `modulo1.py` hazlo como módulo, en la terminal situada en el directorio que contiene a `paquete` haz `python -m  paquete.subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1`.  Cambiando `python` por `python3`, `py3` o lo que sea dependiendo de tu caso. No se si atom tiene alguna forma de hacer esto directamente.

Comment: si tambien pense en eso por lo que, otra solucion que trae fue crear otro archivo `modulo3` que esta en la misma ruta de `modulo1` este `modulo3` tiene la funcion de ejecutar modulo1 , para que actue como main pero el error sigue

Comment: No puedes hacer eso, es lo que intento explicar en la respuesta. Si `modulo3` está en el mismo directorio que `modulo1`, el nombre de este al ser importado por `modulo3` es `modulo1` simplemente no `paquete.subpaquete1.subpaquete2.modulo1`. Para que esto funcione `modulo3` tiene que estar fuera del paquete (`foo.py`). De hecho `modulo3.py` no puede estar  en el mismo directorio que `image.py` ni en ninguno inferior, si esto ocurre `image.py` no podrá ser importada con import relativo desde `modulo1.py`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97388/discussion-between-angel-judath-alvarez-and-fjsevilla).

Comment: FJSevilla: abrí en Meta este debate: [¿Deberían las etiquetas \[import\] e \[importación\] ser sinónimas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4700/83). El consenso parece ir en el sentido de empezar a usar [tag:importación] para la importación de datos y etiquetas específicas tipo [tag:python-import] o [tag:javascript-import] para casos particulares de lenguaje. Iba a empezar a hacerlo y vi muchas muy parecidas. ¿Crees que esta podría servir como canónica para intentar cerrar parte de las otras como duplicadas?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' , primero estoy de acuerdo con el consenso :) En cuanto a las duplicadas, pues es muy posible que pueda servir ésta si no hay alguna con mejores respuestas. Ahora mismo no tengo tiempo de explorar, dentro de un rato miro a ver. Si hay muchas candidatas y son claras podemos coordinarnos por chat por ejemplo y uso a Mjölnir XD y así no saturamos [más] la cola de cierre, a ver si  de paso te echo una mano en el reetiquetado.

Comment: Fantástico, muchas gracias. Y muy contento de que te parezca bien, pues al fin y al cabo eres el que más conoce esta sección de SOes. Cuando puedas, no hay prisa, me dices lo de si te parece bien que esta sea canónica y procedemos con el martillo divino :D