# Llamar a un módulo de python desde otro directorio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Archivo1.py
|
->Archivo2.py
->Archivo3.py
```

(`Archivo2.py` y `Archivo3.py`) están en un subdirectorio bajo `Archivo1.py`)

La idea es que una función que está en `Archivo1.py` llame a otra que está en `Archivo2.py`, y que a su vez ésta importe un módulo que se encuentra en `Archivo3.py`.

El problema es que la función que está dentro de `Archivo2.py` busca el módulo en `Archivo1.py`, y no en `Archivo3.py`

La pregunta es cómo hacer que `Archivo2` busque en `Archivo3`

Muchas gracias

Edito:

No había especificado que el nombre de los directorios puede ser variable, así que a la hora de hacer la llamada no puedo usar:

```
from subpaquete.Archivo3 import foo
```

según la respuesta dada, porque el nombre de subpaquete no esta definido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>No me ha funcionado la respuesta propuesta, pero lo he solucionado así. No creo que sea el método más adecuado, pero funciona (siempre en el caso concreto en el que un módulo esté al mismo nivel que el otro y sea llamado por otro en un nivel ajeno a el de estos dos)</s>

<s>Se trata de obtener la ruta absoluta en la que está localizados los dos módulos implicados, y añadirla al path:</s>

<s>import inspect, os
    directoriodemodulos = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
    import sys
    sys.path.append(directoriodemodulos)</s>

<s>Lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve</s>

Esta solución (la tachada) no es aceptable, ya que los scripts son llamados por otro programa, y cuando hago una segunda llamada, y en caso de módulos con igual nombre pero diferentes subdirectorios me provoca conflictos.

La solución proporcionada por @FJSevilla es la más correcta, pero mi problema particular es que los subpaquetes pueden tener cualquier nombre, así que no puedo definirlos en el propio script, sino que hay que averiguarlos.

Al final esta es la solución más aceptable, sacada de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

```
import importlib
from pathlib import Path
mod_path = Path(__file__).parent
MODULE_PATH = str(mod_path) + "/estilos.py" #este nombre es fijo
MODULE_NAME = "Estilo" #este tambien es fijo
import sys
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(MODULE_NAME, MODULE_PATH)
modulo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[spec.name] = modulo 
spec.loader.exec_module(modulo)
```

Luego, a la hora de llamarlo, he de poner el prefijo:

```
Instancia = modulo.Estilo()
```

Answer (score 3):

Los imports en un paquete se resuelven en base al modulo que es ejecutado como principal. Si tienes una estructura como ésta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dónde tu módulo principal (punto de entrada) es `Archivo1` para importar nombres de `Archivo3` desde `Archivo`2 debes hacer:

```
from subpaquete.Archivo3 import foo

foo()
```

o

```
from subpaquete import Archivo3

Archivo3.foo()
```

también

```
import subpaquete.Archivo3

subpaquete.Archivo3.foo()
```

Otra opción es usar importaciones relativas:

```
from . import Archivo3

Archivo3.foo()
```

o

```
from .Archivo3 import foo

foo()
```

Para una explicación más detallada mírate:

- [No puedo importar paquetes en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285514/no-puedo-importar-paquetes-en-python)

Comment: El caso es que haciendo eso me sale este error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. Al final lo he resuelto obteniendo la ruta absoluta del script y metiéndola en el sys.path. No sé si es una solución muy chapucera, la verdad.