# ModuleNotFoundError Python

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios

```
>Proyecto
 main.py
 >Proyecto2
  main2.py
   IM.py
```

El problema es que al correr main.py me dice que no encuentra el módulo IM.
Pero eso no sucede con main2 y si corro main2 no genera error.

Debo destacar que en el módulo main solo importo el modulo main2 y en el main2 importo el IM.
Quisiera saber ¿Qué puede ser la causa de este error y una posible solución?

Comment: Hola Angel, mirate esta pregunta y mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/285514/15089. La resolución de los imports en un paquete  no depende solo del módulo en el que se importa, depende del módulo que es ejecutado como principal. Como main.py es tu punto de entrada, el import en main2.py debe ser `from Proyecto2 import IM` o usando imports relativos `from . import IM`. si haces algo como `import IM` no funcionará si ejecutas main.py, solo si ejecutas main2.py como módulo principal.

Comment: Gracias por responder lo probé pero ahora me indica que no se encuentra Proyecto2

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no puedes ejecutar main2.py como módulo principal, es un paquete y dichos imports están pensado para que el punto de entrada sea siempre main.py. Si quieres ejecutar main.py como módulo para hacer pruebas cambia  el import temporalmente.

Comment: muy bien gracias y para importar una clase dentro del modulo sigo la misma sintaxis

Comment: Si, por ejemplo, si en `main2.py` quieres importar `Foo` de `IM` deberías hacer `from Proyecto2.IM import Foo` o `from .IM import Foo`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No puedo importar paquetes en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285514/no-puedo-importar-paquetes-en-python)