# Error al importar módulo: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-import

Soy principiante en programación y haciendo este ejercicio para importar un módulo desde un otro archivo me da error:

Éste es mi archivo:

```
from calculos import generales

sumar(7,5)
```

Mi módulo es:

```
def sumar(op1,op2):
    print("el resultado de la suma es: ",op1+op2)

def restar(op1,op2):
    print("el resultado de la resta es: ",op1-op2)

def multiplicar(op1,op2):
    print("el resultado de la multiplicacion es: ",op1*op2)

def dividir(dividendo,divisor):
    print("el resultado de la division es: ",dividendo/divisor)

def potencia(base,exponente):
    print("el resultado de la potencia es: ",base**exponente)

def redondear(numero):
    print("el resultado del redondeo es: ", round(numero)
```

**Nota**: tengo en la carpeta donde esta el modulo el archivo `__init__`.

Este es error que me da:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python\calculos\uso funciones.py", line 4, in <module>
>     from calculos import generales
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculos'
> [Finished in 0.1s]
> ```

Comment: Hola Jose, habría que ver la estructura de archivos de  tu proyecto, pero te recomiendo mirarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285514/no-puedo-importar-paquetes-en-python

Answer (score 0):

Podrías especificar la estructura de tus archivos

**Ejemplo**

```
/Principal
    /Modulos
        /usoFunciones.py
    main.py
```