# ¿Cómo hago llamado a ventanas que se encuentran en una subcarpeta?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy creando un miniprograma en Python, y puedo abrir ventanas en su formato .ui, localizadas en el mismo lugar que mi .py utilizando el siguiente código:

```
uic.loadUi("aaLoquesea.ui", self)
```

Ahora bien, mi pregunta es, si quiero tener mis .ui en una subcarpeta, como hago para realizar la llamada SIN utilizar el típico formato de indicar la ruta entera, puesto que el programa cambia de PC todo el tiempo, y la idea es poder abrirlo sin tener que modificar dicha ruta en cada cambio.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error al tratar de cargar archivo .ui desde otro directorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/286599/15089). Debes usar una ruta relativa o generar la ruta de forma dinámica en base a la ruta del script.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar rutas relativas con respecto a tu ventana principal, pongamos un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo que ejecuta el comando `uic.loadUi()` es el archivo mainView.py por lo que para este caso para llamar a la vista calculator.ui tendrías que usar la ruta relativa de la siguiente manera:

```py
uic.loadUi("views/calculator.ui", self)
```

Por lo que siempre tienes que tener en cuenta donde se encuentra el archivo .ui con respecto al archivo principal que lo manda a llamar.