# if __name__ == '__main__':

Tags: python-3.x

porque hay personas que lo usan ciertamente para disminuir el código, pero no se que hace, cuando debería usarlo, cual es la lógica de uso.. ejemplo.

una lista de números pares...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for number in range(2, 100, 2):
        print(number)
```

de antemano muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

El `if __main__=="__main__:"` es un condicional para evitar que se ejecute una sección del código cuando se importa como un módulo. Para mas info: [pregunta de stackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

El `for number in range(2, 100, 2):` es un for each para todos los numeros desde el 2 hasta el 100 avanzando de a 2 en 2. Para mas info en la funcion range: [doc de python para range](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

La ultima parte es imprime estos numero en la consola

Comment: si es que realmente no entiendo que funciona hace if __main__=="__main__:" y donde y cuando debo usarlo.. porque aqui fue usado en un for muy sencillo el ejercicio pero porque lo usa? cuando lo aplica? es común aplicarlo?

Comment: Hola Jean ¿has mirado las respuestas a la pregunta marcada como duplicado \>\>\> [¿Que es if __name__ == "__main__"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32165/qu%c3%a9-es-if-name-main)</</</?. El condicional se usa cuando quieres que algo se ejecute solo si el módulo es ejecutado como módulo principal y no cuando es importado por otro módulo, realmente no hay mucho más. En tu ejemplo, si ese es todo el código del script, si importas el módulo desde otro no obtendrás absolutamente ninguna salida, en cambio si lo ejecutas como principal te imprimirá los pares.