# Error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, condiciones, vscode, names

## este es mi codigo.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello World'


  if __name__ == '__ main__'
    app.run
```

Comment: Si tu código es precisamente ese, quizás se deba a que el `if` no está en la primera columna

Comment: @luisfer como hago, ¿me podes explicar? por favor.

Comment: Bueno, primero, sería necesario ver completo el error, modifica tu pregunta para ponerlo. No estoy seguro que sea eso, pero parece que es, por la forma en que está redactada la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia

```
if __name__ == '__ main__'
    app.run
```

No debe ir dentro de la función `home()` debe de ir fuera.

En el caso de que esté fuera, debe de ir sin identación, de la siguiente forma:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello World'


if __name__ == '__ main__'
    app.run
```

Te recomiendo esta maravillosa explicación en el que se explica el uso y el por qué de está sentencia: [¿Qué es if __name__ == “__main__”:?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32165/qu%C3%A9-es-if-name-main)

Comment: No está claro que esté dentro del `home()`,  yo hice la edición a la pregunta y respeté los espacios tal como venían, pero igual pudo haber sido un error en la copia

Comment: Tienes razón, de hecho el Home ya tiene puesto su return, he editado la publicación porque en tal caso sería un error de indentación. A ver si da más información.

Comment: Cuando lo edité, respeté los espacios tal como el lo había puesto, también pensé que sería un error de indentación, pero en todo caso no sería un error de sintáxis. No veo error de sintaxis en el código que puso.