# Consulta operaciones entre vectores

Tags: python

este es el enunciado:
Dados dos vectores A y B, de N elementos cada uno, se desean calcular:
a. el vector suma.
b. el producto escalar.

y este es mi programa:

'''

```
    def definir_vectores ():
    texto_vector_a = input("escriba el vector a sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
    lista_vector_a = texto_vector_a.split()
    texto_vecto_b = input("escriba el vector b sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
    lista_vector_b = texto_vecto_b.split()

    return lista_vector_a,lista_vector_b

def suma (a,b):
    vector_suma = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        vector_suma[i].append(a[i] + b[i]) #aca me tira error

    return vector_suma

def producto_escalar (a,b):
    sumatoria = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sumatoria += a[i]*b[i]
    return sumatoria


def main():
    a,b = definir_vectores()
    vector_suma = suma(a,b)
    print ("el vector suma es\n:", vector_suma)
    sumatoria = producto_escalar (a,b)
    print("el producto escalar es\n", sumatoria)


main()
```

'''

Ahi senale donde me tira error, En ese lugar lo que quise hacer es colocar en el subindice i del vector suma, la sumatoria de los vectores a y b indice por indice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estás liando demasiado el problema. Te voy a poner un ejemplo más **"Pythonico"** de como se haría, ya que utilizas un estilo de programación, más usado en otros lenguajes como por ejemplo **C**. El código que yo te propongo es el siguiente:

```
def definir_vectores ():
    texto_vector_a = input("escriba el vector a sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
    lista_vector_a = list(map(float, texto_vector_a.split()))
    texto_vector_b = input("escriba el vector b sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
    lista_vector_b = list(map(float, texto_vector_b.split()))

    return lista_vector_a,lista_vector_b

def vect_sum(v1,v2):
    if len(v1) != len(v2):
        raise ValueError("La longitud de los vectores para multiplicarlos debe ser igual")
    return [x+y for x,y in zip(v1,v2)]

def scalar_product(v1, v2):
    if len(v1) != len(v2):
        raise ValueError("La longitud de los vectores para multiplicarlos debe ser igual")
    return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(v1,v2)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b = definir_vectores()
    print("el vector suma es:\n", vect_sum(a))
    print("el producto escalar es:\n", scalar_product(a, b))
```

Paso a explicarte funciones que puedes tener dudas:

- `list(map(float, texto_vector_a.split()))`: el `map` funciona cualquier operación `map` en otro lenguaje, es decir, es un `for` que va iterando sobre cada elemento de la lista de `texto_vector`. Lo único que **no retorna una lista, si no un objeto, por lo que tendremos que convertirlo a lista**. Con esta operación convertimos los inputs a `floats`
- `sum(v)`: esta es una función built-in de Python, es decir creada por Python para su uso (al igual que map, list, etc), que suma todos los elementos de una lista.

**Ahora vamos al producto escalar:**

1. `if len(v1) != len(v2)`: Lo primero que hacemos es comprobar que el tamaño de los vectores es iguales, ya que si no es igual, no podremos realizar el producto escalar, en ese caso, lanzamos un error propio con `raise ValueError("El número de dimensiones para multiplicar vectores debe ser igual")`
2. `sum([x*y for x,y in zip(v1,v2)])`: aquí aplicamos lo que se conoce como **list comprehension** es algo muy utilizado en python, es la forma de escribir un bucle `for` en una sola linea. `zip()` es otra función **built-in** que agrupa dos listas por indice, es decir, el valor primer valor de `v1` va con el primer valor de `v2`, el segundo valor de `v1`, va con el segundo valor de `v2`, así hasta los N valores que haya en las listas. Una vez los tenemos agrupados, los desagrupamos para poder multiplicarlos. Es decir, con `zip()` hemos agrupado cada par de valores, y ahora iteramos por el valor primero y el valor segundo y los multiplicamos que sería `[x*y for x,y in zip(v1,v2)]`. Por último y para finalizar tendremos una lista de productos escalares multiplicados, por lo que solo nos falta sumar todos los elementos de la lista con `sum()`.

**¿ Y qué es** `__name__ == "__main__":`**?**

Para que te sea sencillo de entender y no extender demasiado la respuesta, **resumiento bastante**, tiene la misma función que `int main(){}` en **C**

Aquí tienes una explicación maravillosa de está función, por si quieres profundizar [¿Qué es if __name__ == “__main__”:?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32165/qu%c3%a9-es-if-name-main)

Comment: El OP tiene definida `suma` con dos argumentos (vectores). Además, define que retorna una lista, no un entero.

Comment: Tienes razón @CandidMoe , Gracias por el apunte, he cambiado la respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Tu codigo tiene dos fallos:

1: cuando usas append() simplemente agregas un elemento a la lista, no tienes que indicar la posicion como en otros idiomas , funciona como el tipico "add()"

2: para poder operar una suma por ejemplo , no puedes sumar dos letras por lo cual tienes que castearlas a Integer para poder operar.

Te dejo el codigo corregido, aplica esta resolucion para arreglar producto_escalar(a,b) ;)

```
def definir_vectores ():
    texto_vector_a = input("escriba el vector a sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
    lista_vector_a = texto_vector_a.split()
    texto_vecto_b = input("escriba el vector b sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
    lista_vector_b = texto_vecto_b.split()


    return lista_vector_a,lista_vector_b

def suma (a,b):
    
    vector_suma = []

    for i in range(len(a)):
       vector_suma.append(int(a[i]) + int(b[i])) 

    return vector_suma

def producto_escalar (a,b):
    sumatoria = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sumatoria += a[i]*b[i]
    return sumatoria


def main():
    a,b = definir_vectores()
    vector_suma = suma(a,b)
    print ("el vector suma es\n:", vector_suma)
    sumatoria = producto_escalar (a,b)
    print("el producto escalar es\n", sumatoria)


main()
```

Comment: ¿ si los números no son enteros ? debieras ajustar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las características importantes de Python es su manejo de listas, que simplifica enormemente la vida es situaciones como esta.

Veamos algunos ejemplos:

**Convertir input a lista numérica**

Estas dos líneas ingresan un vector de **caracteres**;

```
texto_vector_a = input("escriba el vector a sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
lista_vector_a = texto_vector_a.split()
```

El resultado es

```
lista_vector_a = ["1","2", "3"]
```

lo que necesitamos es un vector de valores numéricos. Para eso recorremos el arregla haciendo la conversión usando *comprensión de listas*:

```
texto_vector_a = input("escriba el vector a sin parentesis y separado x espacios:\n")
lista_vector_a = [float(x) for x in texto_vector_a.split()]
```

El resultado sera:

```
lista_vector_a = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Operaciones en paralelo**

Tanto la suma como el producto escalar requieren recorrer ambos vectores en paralelo, operando sobre un valor de cada par.

Python tiene la función **zip**, que toma dos o mas iterable y devuelve una lista de tuplas con los valores pareados.

Ejemplo:

```
vector1 = [1, 2, 3]
vector2 = [4, 5, 6]
for x in zip(vector1, vector2):
    print(x)
```

produce

```
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
```

Esto simplifica los métodos suma y producto escalar. Con un `zip` logramos que Python nos vaya entregando los elementos de ambos vectores pareados:

```
def suma (a,b):
    return [x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(a, b)]

def producto_escalar (a,b):
    return sum(x[0] * x[1] for x in zip(a, b))
```

Espero que te sea útil.